# Extract data using Shell/python script from a text file

Tags: python, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a large text file with data as follows

```
889143359540998144 column=clean-tweet:clean_tokens, timestamp=1511684776520, value=make;sure;youre;ready;safely;view;solar;eclipse;aug;21;check;tip;eclipse;.
```

I need to extract data from it(first id and value) in a format such as below and store it in a text file.

```
889143359540998144   make,sure,youre,ready,safely,view,solar,eclipse,aug,21,check,tip,eclipse,.
```

Can anyone please help in extract this using shell script or python

Comment: show your current code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can think of a fairly easy way using the shell:

```
awk -F'[ =]' '{print $1" "$NF}' your_file.txt | sed 's/;/,/g
```

Assuming your file is named `your_file.txt`

Comment: You don't need the shell or the `sed`, `awk` will do it all: `awk -F'[ =]' '{gsub(/;/, ","); print $1,$NF}' your_file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command:

```
awk -F'[ =]' '{print $1" "$NF}' abc.txt | sed 's/;/,/g
```

Answer (score -1):

You need two commands,

```
awk -F' ' '{print $1 " "$4}' your_file.txt > b.txt
sed -i 's/;/,/g' b.txt
```

You will have expected output in b.txt file.

Note: I am considering that you need to extract data from the file and store it in another file.